# DataView.Rowfilter multiple filter in Loop

Tags: c#, wpf, dataview, rowfilter

```
DataView DV = DataTable.AsDataView();
for(int i=0; i<ConditonQueue.Count; i++)
{
     DV.RowFilter = ConditonQueue.ElementAt(i);
}
```

Here after the loop `DV` is filtered only for last element in `ConditionQueue`. How can I get `DV` with all filter condition on queue applied?
`ConditonQueue.ElementAt(i)` returns a string, which is a valid expression for `RowFilter`.

Combining all `ConditonQueue.ElementAt(i)` will not help in my scenario. I want to apply `RowFilter` each time.

As I need to do some calculation after each `RowFilter`. `AND`ing all conditions will not help.

Is there any other way to recreate the `DV` when `RowFilter` is applied in loop each time?

Comment: RowFilter requires a string expression much like the WHERE statement of SQL (with some differences). What is the return value of ConditonQueue.ElementAt(i)?

Comment: `ConditonQueue.ElementAt(i)` returns a string. Which is suitable expression for RowFilter.

Comment: then what is the issue with this code??

Comment: After control comes out of loop, DV is filtered based on last expression (element) in `ConditonQueue`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lots of assumption as your question is not clear. Try this

```
DataView DV = DataTable.AsDataView();

string[] filter = new string[ConditonQueue.Count];
for(int i=0; i<ConditonQueue.Count; i++)
{
     filter[i] =  ConditonQueue.ElementAt(i).ToString();
}

DV.RowFilter = String.Join(" AND ", filter); // filter1 AND filter2 AND ... AND filterN
```

I don't like your approach, am sorry to say but I think you have to update the DV so that the new filter is applied to already filtered view

```
for(int i=0; i<ConditonQueue.Count; i++)
{
     DV.RowFilter = ConditonQueue.ElementAt(i);
     DV = DV.ToTable().AsDataView();
}
```

Comment: `AND`ing all conditions will not help in my scenario. I want to apply `RowFilter` each time.

Answer (score 1):

The RowFilter ist automatically applied to all rows in the data view. The correct usage would be to combine all conditions of the queue into an appropriate string expression and pass that expression to the RowFilter property.

Also have a look at http://www.csharp-examples.net/dataview-rowfilter/ for examples of the RowFilter syntax.

Comment: I need to do some calculation after each `RowFilter`. `AND`ing all conditions will not help.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to achieve. When you need to do calculations, then apply a condition to the row filter, do your calculations and apply the next condition and so on. (or maybe provide more information what you want to do).

Comment: `DV = DV.ToTable().AsDataView();` inside the loop after `RowFilter` is the solution to my problem. Thanks.